# Cant parse json data from twitter api

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I'm trying to get a list of twitter user names based on the id's, but I can't get jquery to parse to the json data returned by the twitter api. Instead of displaying the names I get: [object Object]. I checked the result and it appears to be valid json data. I need help understanding how to use the data.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=16917715', function(data) {
    var items = [];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
      });
      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'twitter-names-list',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('#follower-names');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to be using JSONP instead of JSON. Generally you can't make cross domain ajax calls and that's probably what's failing here. Here's a good [article on the subject](http://www.fbloggs.com/2010/07/09/how-to-access-cross-domain-data-with-ajax-using-jsonp-jquery-and-php/)

IIRC you can simply add `&callback=?` to your GET request. That would make your request `$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=16917715&callback=?',...`

jQuery will replace that `?` with a dynamic function to process the data and it should work better for you

Comment: I just found this too, if it helps: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/twitter-jsonjsonp-api-url.html

Answer (score 0):

add `&callback=?` to the url to retrieve the data

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=16917715&callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the API, but from looking at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup, it appears that the result is an array of objects.  If I'm reading your code correctly, it appears that you are iterating the array, not the objects' properties in the array.  I would wrap your current `$.each()` call in

```
for( var x = 0; x < data.length; x++ )
{
    $.each(data[ x ], function(key, val){
    ...
    });
}
```

Comment: After looking at your code, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.  At first it looked like you were trying to iterate the properties of the array and list each property, but from your description it seems like you are just trying to make a list of usernames from twitter.  If that's the case, you don't need the $.each, you just need to access the name and id properties of each object in the returned array of users.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my questions. I actuall only need the username for now, but I also wanted to understand how get all properties. I didn't understand why the json data wasn't working, but it's because it's an array instead of an object.

Comment: Not to be a stickler, but if my answer helped you, could you mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark next to my answer?